# PHP multiple image uploads the first image only

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to 'upload' multiple images from one input field. I move them to my "uploads" directory and save their path into my database. The moving part works fine, but for some reason it stores only the first selected image's path and also gives a warning message:

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt in
```

The code:

```
    $filesTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $counted = count($filesTempName);
    $maxSize = 2100000;
    $errorMsg = "";

    if ($counted > 5) {
        $errorMsg = "Maximum 5 images!";
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
            if (empty($filesTempName[$i])) {
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
                $link->close();
            } else {
                $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
                $detectedType = exif_imagetype($filesTempName[$i]);

                if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize) {
                    $errorMsg = "max 2mb!";
                } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                    $errorMsg = "error!";
                } else {
                    $stmt->execute(); //I store other data here, it works fine.
                    $stmt->close();

                    $productid = $link->insert_id;

                    $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images(thumbnailimage, productid) VALUES(?, ?)");
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
                        $file = $filesTempName[$i];
                        if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
                            $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
                            move_uploaded_file($file, $data);
                            $statement->bind_param("si", $data, $productid);
                            $statement->execute(); // I get error for this line
                            $statement->close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This part throws the error:

```
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: You call `$statement->close();` after the `execute()` and then try and use the same statement in the second loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right. It works perfectly now. A last question. Should I put the close tag right after my for cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `$statement->close();` to after loop

```
$filesTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
$counted = count($filesTempName);
$maxSize = 2100000;
$errorMsg = "";

if ($counted > 5) {
    $errorMsg = "Maximum 5 images!";
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
        if (empty($filesTempName[$i])) {
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $link->close();
        } else {
            $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
            $detectedType = exif_imagetype($filesTempName[$i]);

            if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize) {
                $errorMsg = "max 2mb!";
            } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                $errorMsg = "error!";
            } else {
                $stmt->execute(); //I store other data here, it works fine.
                $stmt->close();

                $productid = $link->insert_id;

                $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images(thumbnailimage, productid) VALUES(?, ?)");
                for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
                    $file = $filesTempName[$i];
                    if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
                        $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
                        move_uploaded_file($file, $data);
                        $statement->bind_param("si", $data, $productid);
                        $statement->execute(); // I get error for this line
                        
                    }
                }
                $statement->close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$statement->close();` from your code. You should not be closing the statement or the connection manually. Same goes for `$link->close();`.